# blogdown: Appending an html file into website

Tags: html, r, blogdown

I'm using **blogdown** R package for website development. I want to add some already created **html** files. I wonder how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Could you not use an iframe within the blogdown page?

Comment: Thanks @p0bs for your interest in my problem. I want to put html files in my website and not as a link. Any thoughts.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you able to share examples of these files (to improve our odds of answering the question properly)?

Comment: Thanks @p0bs for your help. You can get the file from [here](https://github.com/myaseen208/R-Workshop/blob/master/testt.html). Thanks

Comment: blogdown is (oversimplifying a bit) nothing more than some Rmd magic wrapped Hugo. https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/ shows that you can have multiple "static" directories or put the html in an "`html`" subdir in `static`. Then ref the HTML from it.

Comment: If you're looking to automagically have HTML pages become part of Hugo, that's not the point of Hugo. Try a `pandoc` conversion of HTML -> markdown then Rmd-ify the markdown and place any static content in the static dir and relatively reference it.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr for your useful comment. Would highly appreciate if you change your comment to answer for future users. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an *egregious* over-simplification: `blogdown` is just a wrapper for Hugo that does some serious magic via R markdown and some extra processing bits.

Within the [Hugo directory structure](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/) lies a `static` directory where any stationary bits — images, CSS, JavaScript, audio, video, general data and even HTML — can be placed.

If you just need the content linkable, you can make a `static/html` directory and place the content there.

Since Hugo's mission in life is to generate HTML from markdown incorporating HTML pages into the Hugo processing workflow is not really " a thing" — *but* — one way to get the existing HTML-ified content into Hugo is to use `pandoc` to convert HTML to markdown and then post-process any referenced content into the appropriate `static` directories. That is a road likely filled with some pain and anguish but possibly worth it if the content really does need to be in the site.

Lasty (and not in the earlier comments). One *really* hack-ish way to get the HTML documents into Hugo is to put them in the aforementioned `static/html` directory then create an Rmd which `<iframe>`s an HTML document with a sufficiently large pane (there's a way to make it fill the browser window and resize — the resizing capability will require use of `pym.js` IIRC) and possibly have a link which will enable folks to "escape the frame" and view the HTML in a tab on it's own.